# Compiler Error: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I keep getting the 1046 error. Here's the code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class MainDocument extends MovieClip {

    private var login:Login;

    public static var STAGE:Stage;
    public static var doc:MainDocument; //needed to easily use methods in other classes


    public function MainDocument() {
        // constructor code
        trace("Main Document is here");
        STAGE = stage;
        doc = this;
        // Set up listeners for UI login and register buttons
        selectLogin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,showLogin);
        selectRegister_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,showRegister);
    } // end function

    private function showLogin(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("Login button is pressed");
        login = new Login();
        login.x = 272;
        login.y = 183;

        addChild(login);
        login.name = "Login";
        STAGE.focus = login.login_txt;
        showMsg("");
    } // end function 

    private function showRegister(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("Register button is pressed");
    } // end function

    public function showMsg(s:String):void{
        welcome_txt.text = s;
    } // end function

} // end class
```

} // end package

The error shows up on this line:

`public static var STAGE:Stage;`

Here's the error:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Stage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly import the `Stage` class.

Where you have

`import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;`

You need to add

`import flash.display.Stage`